# How to create a new window by drag and drop?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

I'm working on implementing 'drag-and-drop' such that dragging a cell in my view would create a new window on the side of my application.

I looked up a lot of resources and they all walk me through dragging and dropping components like images or text. But what I want to achieve is more simple than that: drag a cell from my UICollectionViews and open them in a new window.

From these resources: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/supporting_multiple_windows_on_ipad, https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119136, and How to create a new UIWindowScene from drag'n'drop?, it looks like what I have to do is create a UIDragItem where my cells are being selected, where then the scene:willConnectTo will create the new window based on the NSUserActivity?

If that is correct, which function should I look for within UICollectionView? The project I'm working on is pretty complex and would appreciate any guidance here.